# Passing variables into testng.xml

Tags: maven, testng

I am using maven and testng for my automation framework. In the way it's implemented right now I have to use testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="40" name="Suite" parallel="tests">

  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="version" value="latest"/>
  <parameter name="os" value="windows 10"/>
    <classes>
    <class name="com.package.tests.TestApp"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
  <parameter name="version" value="latest"/>
  <parameter name="os" value="windows 10"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.package.tests.TestApp"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

I am using those parameters above @BeforeMethod to specify in which browsers tests should run.

Is there any way to pass *class names* trough command line?
I've tried ${var} and BeanShell, no luck so far.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, by leveraging the IAlterSuiteListener.

You need to make sure you are using the latest released version of TestNG (6.12 currently).

You then build a listener which implements `org.testng.IAlterSuiteListener` and within it you can basically do anything that you wish. Some of the things that you can do are :

1. Dynamically add/remove `<test>` tags within a `<suite>` tag
2. Dynamically add/remove `<class>` tags within your `<test>` tags (which am guessing is what you are looking for)
3. Change attributes of your suite such as `threadCount` or `parallel` mode etc.,

Here's a simplified sample

```java
public static class Listener implements IAlterSuiteListener {

    @Override
    public void alter(List<XmlSuite> suites) {
        XmlSuite suite = suites.get(0);
        //Pass the value as comma separated via JVM argument -Dclasses=com.foo.bar,com.bar.foo
        String classNames = System.getProperty("classes", "");
        String[] classes = classNames.split(",");
        if (classes.length != 0) {
            XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
            test.setName("another_test");
            List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String className : classNames.split(",")) {
                XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(className.trim());
                xmlClasses.add(xmlClass);
            }
            test.setClasses(xmlClasses);
            suite.setTests(Collections.singletonList(test));
        }
    }
}
```

For more details on this, you can refer to my blog post [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2017/09/29/building-dynamic-testng-suites/)